Harmonic maps of conic surfaces
Let $\Sigma$ be a closed surface of genus $>0$, equipped with a conformal structure $\mathfrak{c}$. Define $\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}}:=\Sigma\setminus \mathfrak{p}$, where $\mathfrak{p}=(p_{1},\ldots,p_{n})\subset \Sigma$, and let $\alpha:=(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n})\in [0,+\infty)^{n}$ such that $\chi(\Sigma)+\sum _{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i}-1)<0$.
Assume that $\alpha:=(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n})\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]^{n}$ and given a hyperbolic metric $h$ with cone singularities of angle $2\pi \alpha_{i}$ at the points $p_{i}$. J. Gell-Redman proved the existence of a unique harmonic diffeomorphism
$$
u\colon (\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},\mathfrak{c})\rightarrow (\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},h)
$$
in the isotopic class of the identity, fixing the each $p_{i}$.
When all $\alpha_{i}=0$, which corresponds to a complete hyperbolic metric $h$ on the $C^{\infty}$ surface $\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}}$, J. Lohkamp proved that there exists a unique diffeomorphism $u$ that is homotopic to the identity map and serves as a harmonic map from $(\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},\mathfrak{c})$ to $(\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},h)$.
I would like to know if there are any references that discuss the same result for a general $\alpha$.
Specifically, is there a unique harmonic diffeomorphism $u\colon (\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},\mathfrak{c})\rightarrow (\Sigma_{\mathfrak{p}},h)
$, where $h$ is a hyperbolic metric with a cone singularity of angle $2\pi \alpha_{i}>0$ at the points $p_{i}$, or a cusp singularity when $\alpha_{i}=0$? Thank you for any comments.
